# Reshaping and grouping part of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I need help pivoting a dataframe

```
data = [{'Start Date': '12/3/2016',
     'End Date': '12/4/2016',
   'Name':'John'},
   {'Start Date':'12/3/2016',
    'End Date': '12/4/2016',
   'Name':'Karen'},
    {'Start Date': '12/1/2016',
     'End Date': '12/2/2016',
   'Name':'John'},
   {'Start Date':'12/1/2016',
    'End Date': '12/2/2016',
   'Name':None},
 {'Start Date': '12/5/2016',
  'End Date': '12/6/2016',
   'Name':'Jeff'},
   {'Start Date':'12/5/2016',
    'End Date': '12/6/2016',
   'Name':'John'}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTkKo.png)

I need it to looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjBO4.png). It doesn't matter which Person column the names end up in so long as they're listed.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be that person1 and person2 are any different other than they happen to be in the same start and end range. Will there always be two people per range in your frame? What's the use case?

Comment: I would be really interested to see an answer which generalizes the case where there is a random number of people, not necessarily common couple rows!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider a merge approach with data frame on itself (akin to SQL's self join) and then filter for non-matched names and first pairing with group count:

```
mdf = pd.merge(df, df, on='End Date')
mdf['grp'] = mdf.groupby('End Date').cumcount()    
#      End Date Name_x Start Date_x Name_y Start Date_y  grp
# 0   12/4/2016   John    12/3/2016   John    12/3/2016    0
# 1   12/4/2016   John    12/3/2016  Karen    12/3/2016    1
# 2   12/4/2016  Karen    12/3/2016   John    12/3/2016    2
# 3   12/4/2016  Karen    12/3/2016  Karen    12/3/2016    3
# 4   12/2/2016   John    12/1/2016   John    12/1/2016    0
# 5   12/2/2016   John    12/1/2016   None    12/1/2016    1
# 6   12/2/2016   None    12/1/2016   John    12/1/2016    2
# 7   12/2/2016   None    12/1/2016   None    12/1/2016    3
# 8   12/6/2016   Jeff    12/5/2016   Jeff    12/5/2016    0
# 9   12/6/2016   Jeff    12/5/2016   John    12/5/2016    1
# 10  12/6/2016   John    12/5/2016   Jeff    12/5/2016    2
# 11  12/6/2016   John    12/5/2016   John    12/5/2016    3

mdf = mdf[(mdf['Name_x'] != mdf['Name_y']) & (mdf['grp']==1)]      # FILTER ROWS
#     End Date Name_x Start Date_x Name_y Start Date_y  grp
# 1  12/4/2016   John    12/3/2016  Karen    12/3/2016    1
# 5  12/2/2016   John    12/1/2016   None    12/1/2016    1
# 9  12/6/2016   Jeff    12/5/2016   John    12/5/2016    1

mdf = mdf[['End Date', 'Name_x', 'Name_y', 'Start Date_x']].\      
        sort_values(['End Date']).reset_index(drop=True)           # SUBSET COLUMNS
mdf.columns = ['End Date', 'Person 1', 'Person 2', 'Start Date']   # RE-NAME COLUMNS
#     End Date Person 1 Person 2 Start Date
# 0  12/2/2016     John     None  12/1/2016
# 1  12/4/2016     John    Karen  12/3/2016
# 2  12/6/2016     Jeff     John  12/5/2016
```